# Get get something of statics properties of Ext.Container when creating item

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have following issue. I have created container with inheriting of 
Ext.Container and creating some items using items array. In constructor 
I'm have asynchronous logic and fill some static properties. I want to use 
value of this static properties when creating items of container. How I can solve this problem? This is important part of my logic.

```
Ext.define('somename', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'somextype',
    id: 'someid',
    statics: {
        property1: false,
        property2: null,
        property3: null
    },
    config: {
        dataAutoId: 'someid',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'so here i want to use value of property1',
            cls: 'some',
            id: 'someid',
            dataAutoId: 'someid'
        }]
    },
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        // here i have implemented some asinhronous logic
        // and as a result set value of property1 
        var statics = this.statics();
        statics.property1 = 'test string';
    }
});
```

I have tried:

```
html: this.statics.property1
```

and

```
html: this.statics().property1
```

but get error:

```
Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded.
```

Edit:

After reading documentation of Sencha Touch 2 I found a solution. 
Asynchronous logic can be done into constructor after this 
we can add items to container. This decision may cause problems if the asynchronous logic take a long time. For this reason it's nice to show a spinner or something similar. This is example code of the solution.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video'
    ],
    static: {
         title: null
    },
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
    },
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var statics = this.statics();
        statics.title = 'test string';
        this.renderItems();
    },
    'renderItems': function() {
        var statics = this.statics();
        this.add([{
            title: statics.title,
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2'
            },

            html: [
                "dfdfhfjYou've just generated a new Sencha Touch 2 project. What you're looking at right now is the ",
                "contents of <a target='_blank' href=\"app/view/Main.js\">app/view/Main.js</a> - edit that file ",
                "and refresh to change what's rendered here."
            ].join("")
        }, {
            title: 'Get Started',
            iconCls: 'action',

            items: [{
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Getting Started'
            }, {
                xtype: 'video',
                url: 'http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c',
                posterUrl: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg'
            }]
        }]);
    }
});
```

Thanks to everyone who gave me advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't databind in this way. The view is first loaded by the framework and later on instantiated. This means that if you want to set `html: this.property1` your static properties not have a value yet.

This works:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.somename', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'somextype',
    id: 'someid',
    statics: {
        property1: false,
        property2: null,
        property3: null
    },
    config: {
        dataAutoId: 'someid2',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'so here i want to use value of property1',
            cls: 'some',
            id: 'someid3',
            dataAutoId: 'someid'
        }]
    },
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        // here i have implemented some asinhronous logic
        // and as a result set value of property1 
        var statics = this.statics();
        this.property1 = 'test string';
        this.down('#someid3').setHtml(this.property1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I want to avoid condititon like this: this.down('#someid3').setHtml(this.property1); is is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded

That simply means you have inconsistency between what your source files are named and what classes they actually declare. For example, you might have a file called Foo.js but it actually contains `Ext.define('Bar'...`.

> In constructor I'm have asynchronous logic and fill some static
>   properties. I want to use value of this static properties when
>   creating items of container. How I can solve this problem?

Just bear in mind: that approach would only make sense if the items are added *after some time* since the construction of your `Container`. Using that approach for items that are specified within the `items` config won't work simply because the items will be created *before* the completion of your asynchronous logic. Therefore, if you need to use those static properties on items specified in the `items` config, you have to take your asynchronous logic outside of your `Container` and only construct it once the properties are available.